# Which git hook could i use for a specific scenario

Tags: linux, git, hook, push

I have a git remote where all users pushes to. Now i want another remote in this remote and it should automatic pushes if it receives commits.

Is that feasible, or do I have to do a `git push -u origin --all` with cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#:%7E:text=new%20URL%20is%20added), you can add another remote url to the existing remote

`git remote set-url --add --push origin <remote-url>`

`git remote -v` should now return two urls configured for `push`.